# is web Form authenticated

Tags: web-to-case

is web Form authenticated. I have to give access of web form to number of people to raise their queries. these users can open this web form , outside the office premises. if web form is not authenticated , how will ensure security of user data and how will ensure it is not subject to hacking
is there any technical document , where all these queries /clauses available

Comment: Hi Poonam, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. I am not the one who down voted you, but your question likely received negative attention because it does not contain much detail. The more specific you are, the more likely you will get useful answers. Please **[edit]** your question to include more information about what you have tried and where you are stuck. Otherwise, your question will likely be closed. As is, it does not contain enough to really help you.

Answer (score 2):

You put the web to lead or case HTML generated in Salesforce on your external facing websites. Now where you place that HTML, if that’s authenticated or not totally depends how you are implementing it at your web layer. It does not have any relation with any data in Salesforce.

From [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setting_up_web-to-case.htm&type=5):

> After enabling and setting up Web-to-Case, generate the HTML code that your webmaster can put on your website so that customers can submit cases.

As for issues around spamming, that is something you should again handle at your web layer.

You can learn more on spam protection on the documentation for [reCAPTCHA to Prevent Spam Cases](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizesupport_web_to_case_enable_recaptcha.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 1):

Web to lead forms do not expose any Salesforce data at any time. There's also no inherent security in web to lead forms; it is up to you to decide which security measure(s) to implement, if any. However, web to lead is also not "hackable" in any real sense, because it can only consume data, not expose data. The only thing you might want to worry about is an anti-spam solution if you're worried about spam bots filling up your lead queue.